# обработка res.json в React

Tags: json, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, express

Товарищи, помогите решить мою проблему ,ситуация такая : 
Есть форма
`<form action="/register" method="post"  >` . 
Есть route

```
router.post('/register',(req,res) =>{
Task.create(req.body).then(()=>{Task.find({},function (err, docs) {
res.json(docs);
```

})})
 , который добавляет в Mongodb новый объект со значениями из формы, а потом отправляет все объекты из базы. Проблемы следующие :

1.какой должен быть правильный ответ  на этот запрос.У меня редиректится на /register и выводит мой  json c коллекцией  [image: Json]

Я же хочу остаться на странице, но куда-то вывести эту коллекцию так,что бы я ее мог спарсить в  React.

2. как собственно эту коллекцию спарсить с помощью  fetch() и JSON.parse()   ( я пытался так, но код не выполнялся, так как меня редиректило на мой JSON )

   ```
   fetch('/register').then(function(data){
            return data.json();
        }).then( json => {
            this.setState({
                taskManager: json
            });
            console.log(this.state.taskManager);
        });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('/register')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
```

попробуй так